# Read all properties files in a directory

Tags: java, spring, properties-file

Right now I am reading properties file in spring as

```
<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="customer/messages" />
</bean>
```

Here I am specifying that read messages.properties in customer directory. But what I want to do is to specify a directory and ask spring to read all properties file present in that directory. How can I achieve that?

I tried  value="customer/*" but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally used approach given on following blog -
http://rostislav-matl.blogspot.in/2013/06/resolving-properties-with-spring.html

Comment: The site is blocked for me, an actual solution would be great!

Comment: Since I've found myself back here, and the edit queue is full, this is the archive link: https://web.archive.org/web/20161023122331/http://rostislav-matl.blogspot.in/2013/06/resolving-properties-with-spring.html

Answer (score 4):

Using `<context:property-placeholder>` is more recommended as:

```
<context:property-placeholder 
    locations="classpath:path/to/customer/*.properties" />
```

You can also do this using Spring 3.1+ Java Config with:

```
@Bean
public static PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer properties(){
  PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ppc = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
  Resource[] resources = new ClassPathResource[ ]
    { new ClassPathResource( "path/to/customer/*.properties" ) };
  ppc.setLocations( resources );
  ppc.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders( true );
  return ppc;
}
```

You may need to tailor the type of resource to load properties from:

- [Resource abstract implementations](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/Resource.html)
- [Built-in resource implementation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#resources-implementations)
- [A complete walk through of properties in Spring](http://www.baeldung.com/2012/02/06/properties-with-spring/)

To use a property, you can use [`Environment`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html) abstraction. It can be injected and used to retrieve property values at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for answering... but the problem with this solution is that I have to write a utility class for reading properties. So how can I get a value for a property at runtime?

Comment: using ResourceBundleMessageSource, I was able to inject messageSource object which can help me in getting values for all properties...

Comment: In the last reference, there is a section that shows how to use such loaded properties. And, also, note that the annotation `@Bean` is Java Config approach alternative to XML configuration and it's **not** a utility class.

Comment: I also updated the answer. You can use `Environment` abstraction that has methods to resolve and get a value for a property. If you need to list all property names, that's a different story.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestions. But I finally used another approach mentioned as answer below.

Comment: Here two issue I am facing with this approach, 1. \*.properties not working to load all files (common/*.properties). 2. If setting a file like "common/common.properties" values are accessible using @Value annotation only, not via autowiring spring Environment

Comment: Class is deprecated since Spring 5.2

Use this one:
`org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`